# Regex battle between maximum and minimum munge

Tags: c#, regex

Greetings, I have file with the following strings:

```
string.Format("{0},{1}", "Having \"Two\" On The Same Line".Localize(), "Is Tricky For regex".Localize());
```

my goal is to get a match set with the two strings:

- Having \"Two\" On The Same Line
- Is Tricky For regex

My current regex looks like this:

```
private Regex CSharpShortRegex = new Regex("\"(?<constant>[^\"]+?)\".Localize\\(\\)");
```

My problem is with the escaped quotes in the first line I end up stopping at the quote and I get:

- On The Same Line
- Is Tricky For This Style Too

however attempting to ignore the escaped quotes is not working out because it makes the Regex greedy and I get

- Having \"Two\" On The Same Line".Localize(), "Is Tricky For regex"

We seem to be caught between maximum and minimum munge. Is there any hope? I have some backup plans. Can you Regex backwards? that would make it easier because I can start with the "()ezilacoL."

**EDIT:**
To clarify. This is my lone edge case. Most of the time the string sits alone like:

```
var myString = "Hot Patootie".Localize()
```

Comment: You can add a positive lookbehind (match backwards). Can you count on the ',' being there? Are you always trying to match lines like these?

Comment: No, Sometimes the string could be alone. the only thing you can count on is "some string".Localize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
\"((?:[^\\"]|(?:\\\"))*)\"\.Localize\(\)
```

Tested on http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html against a number of strings with various escaped quotes.

Looks like most of us who answered this one had the same rough idea, so let me explain the approach (comments after `#`s):

```
\"             # We're looking for a string delimited by quotation marks
(              # Capture the contents of the quotation marks
  (?:          #   Start a non-capturing group
    [^\\"]     #     Either read a character that isn't a quote or a slash
    |(?:\\\")  #     Or read in a slash followed by a quote.
  )*           #   Keep reading
)              # End the capturing group
\"             # The string literal ends in a quotation mark
\.Localize\(\) # and ends with the literal '.Localize()', escaping ., ( and )
```

For C# you'll need to escape the slashes twice (messy):

```
\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|(?:\\\\\"))*)\"\\.Localize\\(\\)
```

Mark correctly points out that this one doesn't match escaped characters other than quotation marks. So here's a better version:

```
\"((?:[^\\"]|(?:\\")|(?:\\.))*)\"\.Localize\(\)
```

And its slashed-up equivalent:

```
\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|(?:\\\\\")|(?:\\\\.))*)\"\\.Localize\\(\\)
```

Works the same way, except it has a special case that if encounters a slash but it can't match `\"`, it just consumes the slash and the following character and moves on.

---

Thinking about it, it's better to just consume two characters at every slash, which is effectively Mark's answer so I won't repeat it.

Comment: @ryber: Just do me a favour and make sure you document this regex right so that its meaning is perfectly clear. The last thing a future developer needs is to come across an undocumented messy regex.

Comment: This fails for me for any string containing an escape sequence "\n" or "\\", it is less clean than some of the other solutions, and it omits the named group.

Comment: @Mark: Oh snap, you're right about escape sequences. That shouldn't be hard to change. Also, adding a named group is trivial since there's already an appropriate capturing group. See my update.

Comment: Excluding both backslashes and quotes and only allowing escaped quotes rejects all other escapes. You need only exclude quotes, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007450/regex-battle-between-maximum-and-minimum-munge/2007547#2007547

Comment: @gbacon: You're forgetting the situation where you're escaping the slash itself: `string = "\\"".Localize()` It's not a valid C# literal, but your regex will accept it.

Comment: Neither is `"\j"` a valid C# literal, but `\\.` as an alternative accepts it (to which you haven't objected). It's pretty clear that ryber is scanning source files whose syntax is already being checked by a compiler, so this is a meaningless quibble.

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

My original answer (below the horizontal rule) has a bug: regular-expression matchers attempt alternatives in left-to-right order. Having `[^"]` as the first alternative allows it to consume the backslash, but then the next character to be matched is a quote, which prevents the match from proceeding.

**Incompatibility note:** Given the pattern below, perl backtracks to the other alternative (the escaped quote) and successfully finds a match for the `Having \"Two\" On The Same Line` case.

The fix is to try an escaped quote first and then a non-quote:

```
var CSharpShortRegex =
  new Regex("\"(?<constant>(\\\\\"|[^\"])*)\"\\.Localize\\(\\)");
```

or if you prefer the at-string form:

```
var CSharpShortRegex =
  new Regex(@"""(?<constant>(\\""|[^""])*)""\.Localize\(\)");
```

---

Allow for escapes:

```
private Regex CSharpShortRegex =
  new Regex("\"(?<constant>([^\"]|\\\\\")*)\"\\.Localize\\(\\)");
```

Applying one level of escaping to make the pattern easier to read, we get

```
"(?<constant>([^"]|\\")*)"\.Localize\(\)
```

That is, a string starts and ends with `"` characters, and everything between is either a non-quote or an escaped quote.

Comment: Yea, thats where we started as well, but its not working. It's starting at "Two Phrases on the same line" and it misses single lines like "Hot Patootie".Localize() completely.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regular expression you need:

```
@"""(?<constant>(\\.|[^""])*)""\.Localize\(\)"
```

A test program:

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Regex CSharpShortRegex =
            new Regex(@"""(?<constant>(\\.|[^""])*)""\.Localize\(\)");

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"))
            foreach (Match match in CSharpShortRegex.Matches(line))
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["constant"].Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Having \"Two\" On The Same Line
Is Tricky For regex
Hot Patootie
```

Notice that I have used `@"..."` to avoid having to escape backslashes inside the regular expression. I think this makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to parse code so one approach might be to evaluate the code on the fly:

```
var cr = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    new CompilerParameters { GenerateInMemory = true }, 
    "class x { public static string e() { return " + input + "}}");

var result = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("x")
    .GetMethod("e").Invoke(null, null) as string;
```

This way you could handle all kinds of other special cases (e.g. concatenated or verbatim strings) that would be extremely difficult to handle with regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Regex(@"((([^@]|^|\n)""(?<constant>((\\.)|[^""])*)"")|(@""(?<constant>(""""|[^""])*)""))\s*\.\s*Localize\s*\(\s*\)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

takes care of both simple and @"" strings. It also takes into account escape sequences.